# Authenticating and Running an EC2 Instance: AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am attempting to create an EC2 instance and then add it to my Auto Scaling group. I am having a lot of issues trying to authenticate. I am looking for a simple way to authenticate a request using my access key to simply start an instance. What I have tried so far:

```
//Authenticate AWS:
var myCredentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  IdentityPoolId:'us-west-2:IdentityPoolID'
}); 

var myConfig = new AWS.Config({
  credentials: myCredentials, region: 'us-west-2'
});

AWS.config = myConfig

var minInst = 1;
var maxInst = 3;

var ec2 = new AWS.EC2();
//Set up parameters for EC2 Instances:
var params = {
  ImageId: 'ami-6e1a0117',
  MaxCount: minInst,
  MinCount: maxInst, 
  InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior: 'terminate',
  InstanceType: 't2.micro',
  Monitoring: {
    Enabled: false
  },
  NetworkInterfaces: [{
    AssociatePublicIpAddress: true,
    DeleteOnTermination: true,
  }],
  Placement: {
    AvailabilityZone: 'us-west-2',
  },
  SecurityGroupIds: [
    'sg-b0307ccd',
  ],
  SecurityGroups: [
    'CAB432Assignment2SG',
  ],

};
ec2.runInstances(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err){
    console.log(err, err.stack); //An error occurred
  }
  else{
    console.log(data); //Successful Response
  }
});
```

I know this code is wrong. I just don't know to fix it. The error I get is:

> CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are logging in with a Cognito account somehow?

Comment: when I just do the config I get no errors. Only get errors when I call runinstances. I am looking for a way to authenticate with my access key

Comment: What access key? I don't see you using an access key in the code anywhere. Are you logging in with Cognito and then obtaining an access key somehow? It sort of sounds like you have a standard IAM access key and secret key, and you are going down the wrong path trying to include this Cognito stuff.

Comment: Yes that is it. i only have a standard IAM access and secret key. This is the closest I could get to regular authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete this section of code entirely:

```
//Authenticate AWS:
var myCredentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  IdentityPoolId:'us-west-2:IdentityPoolID'
}); 

var myConfig = new AWS.Config({
  credentials: myCredentials, region: 'us-west-2'
});

AWS.config = myConfig
```

Change this:

```
var ec2 = new AWS.EC2();
```

To this:

```
var ec2 = new AWS.EC2({region: 'us-west-2'});
```

Then go read this page in the [Setting Credentials in Node.js](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html) documentation. In particular, you need to do one of the following:

- Add an IAM role to your EC2 instance, if this is running on EC2.
- Add an IAM execution role to your Lambda function if this is running on Lambda.
- Create either a `~/.aws/credentials` file with your keys. This can be done with the `aws configure` command if you have [the AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) installed.
- Set the keys as environment variables.

Comment: I am using the shared credentials file. I am now getting the rrror `AuthFailure: Credential must have exactly 5 slash-delimited elements, e.g. keyid/date/region/service/term, got 'access`

Comment: Open your credentials file and verify the values in there.

Comment: It only needs to be called `credentials` and the access key and secret key dont need to be in ""?

Comment: I suggest installing the AWS CLI tool and running the `aws configure` command to create the file in the correct format.

Comment: Does the error still say "got `access" ? That's telling you that it is finding the word "access" where it expects a key to be. Make sure you don't have an invalid environment variable set, as it will try to use that first if it exists.

Comment: yes it does. I have double checked the credentials file that it generated and my access keys are definitely in there. in aws configure I made the defualt output format json which is what a tutorial said. Should that work?

Comment: The default output format is for the CLI tool and doesn't affect the SDK. Like I said, make sure you don't have credentials configured in some other way that would override the credentials file. Try running this command: `echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`

Comment: I know this next question is a bit off topic but I don't think it warrants me writing another question. I am now getting an invalid availability zone. It is set to `us-west-2` as you showed in your answer.

Comment: `us-west-2` is a region, not an availability zone. An availability zone would look like `us-west-2a`, `us-west-2b` etc.